# Streaming single element from list in akka stream using java api

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream

I am using akka stream java library. My use case is I need to do IO intensive operation on list. so I am using groupedwithin to group element and then using mapAsync to do io operation on it. I want each element of the list to stream downwards. I tried and found that we can use mapConcat(identity) to achieve this but equivalent to identity is not present in java.
Please suggest me some approach to go with this use case?

```
Source.<x>queue()
    .groupedWithin(100, batchInterval)
    .mapAsync(10,A::B) // will return list
    .mapConcat(?)      // looking for equivalent of identity in akka
    .map(C::D)         // accept single element
```

I found that we can do this

```
mapConcat(list -> list)
```

Is this the correct way of using mapConcat?

Comment: Yes, it does. Nothing from with using identity function like you did.

Comment: Or use Java's built-in [`Function.identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--)